# add class which contains array to firebase android java

Tags: java, android, firebase

i have class user and i want to save it to firebase when user signUp , my code worked well when i remove 'image' and
'phone' because they type array i think.. but when i add them data dosn't save in firebase
and i get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hwada, PID: 24561
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:161)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:61)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
        at com.example.hwada.views.SignUp.onClick(SignUp.java:98)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

my code

```
            String _email = email.getText().toString();
            String _phone = phone.getText().toString();
            String _username = username.getText().toString();

            User userModel = new User(_username,_email,_phone,getUserDefaultImage());
            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            //save user data
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("profile");
            databaseReference.push().setValue(userModel);
```

and this is how i convert img to byte[]

```
 private byte[] getUserDefaultImage(){
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.person);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

class user

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private  String username;
    private  String email;
    private  ArrayList<String> phone;
    private byte[] image;
    private  String aboutYou;
    private  String gender;
    
    public User(String username, String email, String phone,byte[] image) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.aboutYou ="";
        this.gender ="";
        //phone
        this.phone = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.phone.add(phone);
        this.image =image
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: nothing added to firebase

Comment: if i remove phone and image from class it worked well and data saved but when add them like above the all data not saving

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the serValue() operation, to see if something went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite explicit: you can't store Java arrays in the Firebase Realtime Database.

In addition, it can only store JSON types and `byte[]` is not a JSON type. If you want to store binary data in the Realtime Database, you'll have to store it as base64 data. But *do* consider if you really want to store binary data in a database, or if [uploading them to Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) is a better solution.

If the `ArrayList` is also giving problems, try declaring it as just a `List` or `List<Object>`, to see if Firebase accepts that.